# Can you filter posts by meta key with the getEntitityRecords selector?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

As my first foray into WP5-era theme development I am trying to develop blocks to replace where I would normally use shortcodes and a metabox plugin. After a lot of learning I have finally managed to do everything I needed besides one (hopefully tiny) snag in a dynamic block that I am not sure how to get around.

The block I have made displays posts from a custom post type ("team") where a custom field ("featured") is set to true. I was naively hoping that I could just add meta parameters to my query like in WP Query but it seems not (at least with the various syntax I have tried..!) It works fine besides that it returns everything not just "featured" ones.

```
posts: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'team', { order: 'asc', orderBy: 'menu_order', per_page: -1, metaKey: 'featured', metaValue: true } )
```

When I log the returned posts to the console, the value for featured is there so worst case I can use that to only render the ones I want but I would prefer to do it properly and only query the ones I need if that's not terribly convoluted.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(In hurry? Skip to the bottom for the code..)*

So Gutenberg or the Block Editor uses the WordPress REST API when retrieving entity (e.g. `postType>post` and `taxonomy>category`) records (e.g. posts and terms).

For examples, for posts (post type of `post`), the route is `/wp/v2/posts`.

And for custom post types such as `team`, the default route is `/wp/v2/team` — you can change the `team` part via the `rest_base` parameter when you register the post type, which defaults to the post type slug.

But despite the routes are different, the default controller for posts (i.e. `postType` entity records) request is [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/), which you could change via the `rest_controller_class` parameter when registering the post type.

Having said that, you can see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments) for all the default parameters supported by that controller, and which one would supply as properties of the object in the third parameter of the `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords()`:

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post', {
  per_page: 2,
  orderby: 'title',
  ...
} );
```

***Now if you look at those [default parameters list](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments), filtering the posts by metadata is (currently) not supported.***

However, the good thing is that the default posts controller (`WP_REST_Posts_Controller`) has a [hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L269) you can use to modify the query/`WP_Query` parameters:

```
/**
 * Filters the query arguments for a request.
 *
 * Enables adding extra arguments or setting defaults for a post collection request.
 *
 * @since 4.7.0
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
 *
 * @param array           $args    Key value array of query var to query value.
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request The request used.
 */
$args       = apply_filters( "rest_{$this->post_type}_query", $args, $request );
```

So in your case, you could make the meta query works like so:

```
add_filter( 'rest_team_query', function( $args, $request ){
    if ( $meta_key = $request->get_param( 'metaKey' ) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = $meta_key;
        $args['meta_value'] = $request->get_param( 'metaValue' );
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

That is just a basic example, but the main point is that you can use the `rest_{post type slug}_query` hook to filter the query.

And then in your `getEntityRecords()` call:

```
wp.data.select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'team', {
  // Default args.
  per_page: 2,
  orderby: 'title',

  // Custom args.
  metaKey: 'featured', // filter by metadata
  metaValue: '1' // not "true" unless the database value is exactly "true" (string)
} );
```

Comment: Amazing - thank you Sally, you're a star! That works perfectly and I will definitely read up more on REST and what else I can do in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if ( $meta_key = $request->get_param( 'metaKey' ) ) {` be an equality check `===` not set the value `=`?

Comment: No, @spnzr. I was checking if the param `metaKey` is set and then I assigned its value to `$meta_key`. I.e. I check and define it.

Comment: oh yeah – otherwise the $metakey is undefined. my linter picked it up

Comment: That is correct, @spnzr. But actually, we could also do `if ( ! empty( $request['metaKey'] ) )` and then `$args['meta_key'] = $request['metaKey'];` - i.e. make direct array access on the request object and there'd be no need to define the `$meta_key` variable. ( PS: Thanks for the +1.. :) )