# getEntityRecords/useEntityRecords: How to use CPT metadata?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, block-editor, meta-query, core

I use `getEntityRecords` as described in the official data API tutorial (https://learn.wordpress.org/lesson/retrieving-wordpress-data-records/).

I.e.:

```
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState( '' );
    const pages = useSelect( select => {
        const query = {};
        if ( searchTerm ) {
            query.search = searchTerm;
        }
        return select( coreDataStore ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'myCustomPostType', query );
    }, [searchTerm] );
```

This works fine and as expected. Now I want to adjust the query so that the posts' meta can be used to reduce the query result.

I tried various approaches such as

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState( '' );
const pages = useSelect( select => {
    const query = {};
    if ( searchTerm ) {
        query.search = searchTerm;
    }
    if (postId) {
      query.meta = [
        {
        myMetaKey: postId,
        },
        ];
     }
    return select( coreDataStore ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'myCustomPostType', query ); 
}, [searchTerm] );
```

but to no avail.

As I understand the 'getEntityRecords' [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/#getentityrecords):

> *query* **GetRecordsHttpQuery**: Optional terms query. If requesting
> specific fields, fields must always include the ID. For valid query
> parameters see the [Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) in the REST API Handbook and select the
> entity kind. Then see the arguments available for “List [Entity
> kind]s”.

querying the metadata should be possible.

I'm aware of [meta_query with standard getEntityRecords possible?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/418121/meta-query-with-standard-getentityrecords-possible) but am not fully sure if it relates to this problem.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer myself thanks to [Can you filter posts by meta key with the getEntitityRecords selector?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341905/can-you-filter-posts-by-meta-key-with-the-getentitityrecords-selector)

Despite my first understanding the >>>query<<< parameters for list posts given in the [Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments) do >>>not<<< contain the meta.

I followed the article and created a query filter for the CPT, i.e.

```
    function mycustomposttype_meta_query_filter()
    {
      add_filter(
        'rest_mycustomposttype_query',
        function ($args, $request) {
          if ($meta_key = $request->get_param('metaKey')) {
            $args['meta_key'] = $meta_key;
            $args['meta_value'] = $request->get_param('metaValue');
          }
          return $args;
        },
        10,
        2
      );
    }
```

(NB the slug name 'rest_mycustomposttype_query' => you'll need to adopt this to your custom post type) and added it in my CPT's class constructor:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'mycustomposttype_meta_query_filter'));
```

Now I can query as such

```
query.metaKey = 'customMetaKey';
query.metaValue = customMetaValue;
```

If anybody wants to contribute a more generic approach (multiple key/value meta query parameters) - welcome. This at least is sufficient to solve my current challenge.